# Why can't I use ToolButtons after assigning them an Action?

Tags: delphi

I am learning Delphi and building a simple NotePad. However, as soon as I add an `Action` to some ToolButtons (note the align left, center, and right buttons and Bold), they are disabled in the running app, although the `Enabled` property is set to true in the Object Inspector. They become enabled in the running app if I remove the `Action` from them in the Object Inspector, but then they are just useless clickable buttons. I have added some pictures below.

I have Googled and tried myself almost to insanity and I really can't figure it out myself.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Did you by chance disable the action you assigned to the buttons? If the action is disabled, the buttons will mimic this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal `TAction` needs an `OnExecute` event to become enabled. You can control this with the property `DisableIfNoHandler`, which defaults to `True`.

Comment: Thanks, it works with onExecute events. I guess the confusion came from an older tutorial video, where everything worked out-of-the-box.